# Google places API returning failed to open stream: HTTP request failed error

Tags: google-places-api, http-status-codes

I am hoping for some direction on this error. I have a loop that connects with the google places API. Every few times I test it I get an HTTP request failed error. But when I take the API call from the error it works in a browser or in postman. Any suggestions for what might be causing this? Thanks for all of your help. Here is my API call and the error.

```
$googleApiPlaceUri = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json';
        foreach ($attractions as $attraction) {
            $api_call = "{$googleApiPlaceUri}?query={$attraction}+in+{$city}&key={$api_key}";
            $api_return_array[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_call));
            foreach ($api_return_array as $result) {
                $results = $result->results;
                array_push($results_array, $results);
            }
        }
```

Here is the error I get...

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hiking +in+Denver&key=API_KEY): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: is API_KEY actually getting replaced with your key? I also think it could be the space between `hiking +in+`, notice the space after hiking.

Comment: The API key is being replaced, I just didn't post the key here. I don't think there is a problem with the spacing because if I copy the URL directly from the error, it works fine in a browser or in postman. This is also a loop and in this case, it worked fine for twice and returned this error once. I also just tried the same search terms in a different order and it worked fine. I am not sure why this error only comes up sometimes.

Comment: In the browser it's going to get URL encoded which will handle the space. I don't know about postman but it may do that also. Maybe just fix it once and try it to rule that out?